# Detect privilege escalation attacks where user gains SYSTEM account privileges - Windows

Tags: windows-server-2012, azure, windows-server-2016, microsoft-ata

We have an audit requirement from a client to be able to monitor for "User obtained SYSTEM privileges".

We are running a Windows Server 2012/2016 environment in Azure and using Azure Log Analytics and Microsoft ATA for security monitoring/reporting.

I've looked all over the place, and I'm starting to think that it's not possible to track this. Can someone confirm if it is possible, and how it could be done??

Comment: You might look at event ID 4756 and 4728 for any new users that get domain admin, schema admin, or enterprise admin. Also look for event ID 4672 on any other server for local escalations.